# Do I save fees through “import”?

Tags: import, solidity, fee

For example, if I import these two instead of the code:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Do I then save fees when deploying?

Then I heard that you don't even have to import Safemath from 0.8.0 Solidity onwards, so it's redundant. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The compiled bytecode is the same when you import another `.sol` file, as well as when you include its content in the original.

So there's no difference in deployment gas fees.

---

> *you don't even have to import Safemath from 0.8.0 Solidity onwards, so it's redundant*

This is correct. Since Solidity 0.8, the overflow/underflow checks are performed automatically, which makes the SafeMath library redundant.